# HighCharts loading error - undefined is not a function

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, highcharts

I am working with HighCharts following RailsCasts and HighCharts documentation.
I am trying initial chart as per the doc -

```
$(function () { 
  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Fruit Consumption'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Fruit eaten'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [1, 0, 4]
    }, {
        name: 'John',
        data: [5, 7, 3]
    }]
  });
});
```

I have `highcharts.js` file in my `apps/assets/javascripts/` location and `application.js` set up as -

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require highcharts
//= require_tree .
```

When I run my page I don't get any chart but can see `undefined is not a function` as an error in Dev tools console.

I understand that this issue may be due to the fact that jquery has to load before highcharts, but I am all confused with this asset pipeline.

I have `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>` in my application.html.erb

My DevTools shows that highcharts.js has been loaded, only issue I can think of is there are 2 instances of jquery and highcharts.js is between them inside the `<head>`.

Comment: If you have asset digestion disabled, have you confirmed that all of your assets are being loaded, including highcharts? You can check this via the developer console, to make sure that they are all loading. You might also try removing Turbolinks to see if that is causing an issue.

Comment: Besides examining the rails server console, you could also check if the issue is related to environment setting and use "Developer Tools" > "Sources/Resources" to ensure "highcharts.js" is loaded.

Comment: Highcharts is loaded. I can see in sources of Dev tools.

Comment: Maybe you load highcharts after chart initialise? Have you check if you don't have a async option anywhere?

Comment: How do I check this? I looked into all of my files. In Devtools, I'm seeing 2 instances of jQuery being loaded and highcharts.js is between it.

Comment: Honestly Im not familiar with rails.

Comment: would you also have included by mistake ``HighchartsAdapter.js``? If it is the case, remove it, reload.